# Automatically add brackets to complete JSON file

Tags: json, stack, curly-braces

I have the first half of a JSON file. What's the easiest way to figure out the "missing" brackets (a mixture of `}` and `]`) to append in order to get valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Well not the most elegant solution but my JSON was well formatted and all brackets were at the end of a line except for those with commas. I read the file line by line, stripped off the commas, and pushed/popped from a stack, being left with the opening brackets that I needed to close.

```py
stack = []

with open("incomplete.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            line = line.strip()
            if line and line.endswith(","):
                line = line[:-1]        
            c = line[-1]
            if c in ("{","["):
                stack.append(c)
            elif c in ("}", "]"):
                stack.pop()
        except Exception as e:
            pass

print(stack)
# >>> ['{', '{', '[', '{', '[']
```